# IdTCPClient sometimes connect to 224.0.0.252:5355

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy

I have a IdTCPClient on my application and my firewall inform me about an outgoing connection  to 224.0.0.252:5355. In the connection properties the used protocol is UDP.

I've searched for "224.0.0.252" and found that it's an IP multicast address (Link-local Multicast Name Resolution)

Q: Why IdTCPClient try to do that?

[image]

Comment: What code results in this behaviour?

Comment: Noting, application works as normal. Even if I deny the request.

Comment: UDP is a different protocol, TIdTCPCLient can not be the source of the UDP connection.

Comment: I'm surprised about that, but the firewall confirmation message is clearly indicate that the used protocol is UDP. I've a IdTCPServer too. IDK can it be the source of connection?

Answer (score 7):

As its name suggests, TIdTCPClient only supports **TCP** not **UDP**.

UDP 224.0.0.252:5355 is used by Microsoft in modern Windows versions for [Link Local Multicast Name Resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_Multicast_Name_Resolution) (defined in [RFC 4795](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4795)) as part of their hostname-to-IP lookups when conventional DNS is not available.

When you ask `TIdTCPClient` to connect to a hostname, it asks the OS to resolve the hostname to an IP address before then connecting to it.  Your Windows version is obviously utilizing LLMNR as part of that resolution, and your firewall is picking up on that.  That is happening outside of Indy.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I'm surprised about that, but the firewall confirmation message is clearly indicate that the used protocol is UDP. Also I only used IP address and don't used any hostname (I am on a local net).

Comment: Indy does not use LLMNR directly, only the OS does. `TIdTCPClient` does not use UDP, only TCP. If you set the `Host` to a valid IP then `TIdTCPClient` does not ask the OS to resolve it, so LLMNR is not possible. Double-check your `Host`.

Answer (score 0):

The connection to 224.0.0.252:5355 with protocol UDP is used by recent versions of Windows for Link Local Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR) searching for local network computers.
If you have no local network you may disable LLMNR with a peculiar registry setting.
Create and execute the file "disable-LLMNR.reg" containing:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient]
"EnableMulticast"=dword:00000000
```